# Proper way to map a join table with additional properties in EF 6 CodeFirst

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I have a table -- Instruments.  This table has an PK of InstrumentId and columns like Book, Page, DocumentTypeId, etc.

I have another table -- Orders.  This table stores information about a filter created by a user.  The PK is OrderId and it has columns like OrderName, etc.

The idea is that a user creates an order and defines the filter for the order.  When the filter is applied, a resulting set of matching Instruments is returned.  The user will then look through the matches and add notes and/or "favorite" flag to each match.

I need to store the list of matching instruments for each order as well as the user notes, etc.

Since multiple user orders may reference the same Instruments, I cannot simply add notes to instrument and call it a day.

Typically, I'd add a third table called Matches.  This table would have the following columns: OrderId, InstrumentId, IsFavorite, Notes.  Basically, a join table with some additional fields.

If it were a simple join issue (no IsFavorite or Notes), the I would do the following (assuming the POCO objects area already created):

```
public OrderConfiguration()
{
    ToTable("orders");
    HasKey("orderid");
    ...
    HasMany(o => o.Matches).WithMany().Map(x =>
    {
       x.ToTable("matches");
    };
}

public InstrumentConfiguration()
{
    ToTable("instruments");
    HasKey("instrumentid");
    ...
}
```

However, am I correct that because I have additional properties (IsFavorite & Notes) relating to the relationship between the two entities (Order and Instrument), I now have to introduce both a new table and a new entity?  IOW, I can't just throw those columns into my Matches table and somehow map them correct?  I have to add a new entity -- MatchedInstrument?  MatchedInstrument would look something like:

```
public class MatchedInstrument 
{
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public int InstrumentId {get; set;}
    public bool IsFavorite {get; set;}
    public string Notes {get; set;}
}
```

I would then add a MatchedInstrument table that has Id, IntrumentId, etc.  And then I would have to change Matches table to have OrderId and MatchedInstrumentId?

Is this the correct way to handle this?

Comment: you can define a new entity `MatchedInstrument` to configure many to many relationship, or just create the `MatchedInstrument` table only in the database, check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620#ManyToMany) as reference ..

Comment: Part of the question is, if I only define a table in the database, how do I populate the additional properties (IsFavorite and Notes)?

Comment: Ouch, I forgot about the very basic requirement (additional properties), you need the `MatchedInstrument` Entity :)

Comment: the `MatchedInstrument` need the OrderId too btw, and does the matched instrument per user ? if so, you also need UserId..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create the relationship as follow.

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Instrument> Instruments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
public class Instrument
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Book { get; set; }
    public string Page { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MatchedInstrument> MatchedInstruments { get; set; }
}
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OrderName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MatchedInstrument> MatchedInstruments { get; set; }
}
public class MatchedInstrument
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int InstrumentId { get; set; }
    public Instrument Instrument { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public bool IsFavorite { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yuliam.  Actually the Orders are per user.  However, you answered my question in regards for the need for the extra entity.  Thanks for the help.